# Hive UDF function processing order (comparing 2 values)

Tags: process, hive, hiveql

I have a list of values for a specific field (state) sorted by dates. I want to display only the lines which state has changed from the previous date:
Example input:

```
date                  state
2013-01-15 04:15:07.602 ON
2013-01-15 05:15:08.502 ON
2013-01-15 06:15:08.502 OFF
2013-01-15 07:15:08.502 ON
2013-01-15 08:15:08.502 ON
...
```

Output expected

```
date                    state
2013-01-15 04:15:07.602 ON
2013-01-15 06:15:08.502 OFF
2013-01-15 07:15:08.502 ON
```

My hiveql query is like this

```
select date, state from demo_bd where statechanged(state) sort by date
```

`statechanged()` is my UDF java function that returns true only if the current state is different from the previous one. This function works fine in java.
My problem is that while it seems to work for the first hundreds values then it fails and sometimes (not everytime) I get the same state for 2 adjacent dates…
I really don’t see where the problem comes from. Is it related to the way and order hive processes the data?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're observing nondeterministic results because your query is being executed with multiple reducers.  From the [Hive documentation on SORT BY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy):

> The difference between "order by" and "sort by" is that the former guarantees total order in the output while the latter only guarantees ordering of the rows within a reducer. If there are more than one reducer, "sort by" may give partially ordered final results.

For this particular use case, you may have to try to force the allocation of just a single reducer to guarantee accuracy.  Unfortunately, this will probably also mean a performance penalty since a single reducer task will be looking through the entirety of the table.